# Apache only serves first level of Django static files directory

Tags: django, django-admin, apache2

I have a site I made with Django, and I'm trying to deploy it on an Apache server I have lying around (using mod_wsgi as recommended by the official docs) and for the most part, everything's going great. I am having a problem getting Apache to correctly serve the static files associated with my project. Judging by comparing the source of the rendered HTML with my server's file structure, I would say that my app is requesting the right files from the right locations, but for whatever reason Apache throws me a 404. Here's my config for apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName book
    ServerAlias www.book.dev book.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/book


    Alias   /static/        /var/www/book/static
    Alias   /media/         /var/www/book/media

    <Directory /var/www/book/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rich/sites/book/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/rich/sites/book>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I navigate to `STATIC_ROOT` in my web browser (in this case `www.book.dev/static`) I see a (correct) listing of the first level in the directory structure on the server. However, trying to follow the links to sub-directories, or even files in the root directory, yields only a 404. I'm using Django 1.3, Python 2.6, and some version of apache in the 2.X range (whatever is the most recent version in debian's package repo)

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT: (The plot thickens!)**

So, after fiddling some more, I found something that I thought was interesting. I discovered that if I run the development server, the URL's from which static content is fetched are **identical** to the static file URL's which are generated when Apache is serving the files. This is to say, they all take the form `/static/<file>` as configured in `settings.py`, but sometimes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having:

```
Alias   /static/        /var/www/book/static/
Alias   /media/         /var/www/book/media/
```

If using trailing slashes for a sub URL, the target file system path should have a trailing slash as well.

Compare to documentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting_Of_Static_Files

Comment: I must have read that documentation 3 or 4 times before asking the question here... I can't believe I didn't notice the trailing slashes! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your settings.py. Look for commas and logic of directory structure. Especially about STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA ... dirs.
Problems are often not where they came from.

And you can create a symink to apache dir... and take it to where it was on your project at dev file structure... Try it may show your errors in templates if they exist...